# Get first observation of month in yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to get the first Ibovespa observation of the month using data from `yfinance` library. I made the following code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()


wb.get_data_yahoo('^BVSP',
                         start = '2019-10-03', 
                         end = '2020-05-01',
                         interval='1mo')['Adj Close']


Date
2019-10-31    108233.0
2019-11-30    115645.0
2019-12-31    113761.0
2020-01-31    104172.0
2020-03-01     73020.0
2020-04-01     80506.0
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

This is not the result I want. I need the observation of the first working day of the month. Something similar to this:

```
Date
2019-10-01    108233.0
2019-11-01    115645.0
2019-12-01    113761.0
2020-01-01    104172.0
2020-03-01     73020.0
2020-04-01     80506.0
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

How to proceed to reach this result?

Comment: There are many approaches, but I think it would be easy to retrieve data on a daily basis and group the results by year and month to get the first row. `df = wb.get_data_yahoo('^BVSP', start = '2019-10-01', end = '2020-05-01', interval='1d')['Adj Close'].to_frame();df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).head(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Tried to print your dataframe at `monthly` intervals, all data on the first day. Perhaps the market is still closed and this is the reason ..? True, if you look at the daily data, then the `first day` in January is the `second number`.

I can suggest taking daily data and `grouping` them by `year, month` and using `aggregate('first')` to take the first value.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as wb


yf.pdr_override()

df = wb.get_data_yahoo('^BVSP',
                       start='2019-10-03',
                       end='2020-05-01',
                       interval='1d')['Adj Close']

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month]).aggregate('first')
df = df.set_index('Date')
```